# html: Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use Rounded Corner buttons in my ASP.NET website using AjaxControlToolkit's RoundedCornerExtender. When I use this on a Buton control, I get an error saying "htmlfile: Unexpected call to method or property access" to which I can Break/continue.

When I run the sites, it gives me an error "Unexpected call to mathod or property access".Here's the screenshot: http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/7051/roundedcornersp.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my are of expertise, but I would guess this does not work on a button control.
You could try using a div as button.

Here is the same discussion:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1352765/2766571.aspx

Comment: umm.. not working on a button? I saw a sample here on asp.net/ajax -> http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/RoundedCorners/RoundedCorners.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but where do you see this applied to a button?

Comment: oops...sorry! Did know that! There isn't any video available one their available there on asp.net/ajax to use Round Corner extender. Can you please inscribe some steps on how to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but is there something wrong with using other purely javascript solutions to rounded corners that are out there?

Comment: I have to use Code-behind events on these buttons as well

Comment: @user458790: Understood, but unless Code-behind events are determining whether the buttons should have rounded corners, the two topics are apples and oranges. Using javascript to round corners has nothing to do with ASP.Net. ASP.Net emits a HTML INPUT tag when passed to the client, at which point, JavaScript or CSS is used to style that element. ASP.Net needn't be involved in that process.